# Can't delete a file after thread is interrupted

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm kinda lost on this one ; i've tried everything i know for doing such operation and the error persists.

I've a FileProcessor class that creates a new thread, do some operations, etc ; however, even when manually calling Dispose() inside it and Thread.Interrupt() i can't seem to delete the files after use.

First i was doing this code using an async method on the main thread ; now i've switched to threading with this FileProcessor, just trying to delete those files after the operation.

I can delete one or two files, but when it gets to the third file it throws an System.IOEXception

I truly don't know what else can i do. Any input is appreciated.
I was using Worker.Join inside Dispose() and waiting for the thread to finish or the GC ends it - but neither of em ever happened.

Thanks

My code (reduced as possible)
Form1:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool RestartTimer;
        private bool ThreadRunning;
        FileProcessor TIFFtoXMLProcessor;
        FileProcessor CIP3toTIFFProcessor;
        List<string> files;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TIFFtoXMLProcessor = new FileProcessor();
            RestartTimer = false;
        }
        private void BeginWork()
        {
            TIFFtoXMLProcessor.EnqueueFileName(@"C:\test\yourtestfile1.txt");
            TIFFtoXMLProcessor.EnqueueFileName(@"C:\test\yourtestfile2.txt");
            TIFFtoXMLProcessor.EnqueueFileName(@"C:\test\yourtestfile3.txt");
            files = new List<string>(TIFFtoXMLProcessor.fileNamesQueue);
            TIFFtoXMLProcessor.eventWaitHandle.Set();
            if(TIFFtoXMLProcessor.worker.IsAlive == false)
            {
                foreach(var item in files)
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The FileProcessor class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class FileProcessor : IDisposable
    {
        public EventWaitHandle eventWaitHandle { get; private set; }
        public Thread worker { get; private set; }
        private readonly object locker = new object();
        public Queue<string> fileNamesQueue { get; private set; }
        public string currConversion { get; private set; }
        public bool JobComplete { get; private set; }        
        private CancellationTokenSource cancelParallelWorker;
        public string ColorSeparator { get; private set; }        
        private readonly TextBox tbStatus;
        public string outputFolder { get; private set; }
        List<string> filesgoingtorun;

        //var AvailableJobsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        //string nZones, string zWidth, string fzWidth, string lzWidth, string zAreaWidth, string zAreaHeight, double DPI
        public FileProcessor()
        {

            eventWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            fileNamesQueue = new Queue<string>();
            // Create worker thread
            worker = new Thread(Work)
            {
                IsBackground = true
            };
            cancelParallelWorker = new CancellationTokenSource();
            worker.Start();
        }
        public void EnqueueFileName(string FileName)
        {
            // Enqueue the file name
            // This statement is secured by lock to prevent other thread to mess with queue while enqueuing file name
            lock (locker) fileNamesQueue.Enqueue(FileName);
            // Signal worker that file name is enqueued and that it can be processed
            //eventWaitHandle.Set();
        }
        private void Work()
        {
            List<string> filesToWork = new List<string>();
            while (true)
            {
                string fileName = null;
                // Dequeue the file name
                lock (locker)
                    while (fileNamesQueue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        fileName = fileNamesQueue.Dequeue();
                        filesToWork.Add(fileName);
                        if (fileName == null) return;
                    }
                if (fileNamesQueue.Count == 0 && filesToWork.Count > 0)
                {
                    var tempList = new List<string>(filesToWork);
                    filesToWork.Clear();
                    ProcessJob(tempList);
                }

            }
        }
        private void ProcessJob(List<string> filesToWork)
        {
            try
            {
                JobComplete = true;
                switch (currConversion)
                {
                    case "TIF":
                        {
                            int j = 0;
                            foreach (var currJob in filesToWork)
                            {
                                //Series of tasks...
                                j++;
                            }
                            eventWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                            break;
                        }
                }
                JobComplete = false;
                Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception conversionEx)
            {
                cancelParallelWorker?.Cancel();                
            }
        }   
        #region IDisposable Members
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Signal the FileProcessor to exit
            EnqueueFileName(null);
            // Wait for the FileProcessor's thread to finish
            worker.Interrupt();
            // Release any OS resources
            eventWaitHandle.Close();
        }

        #endregion
    }

}
```

Comment: The word "Minimal" in "[mcve]" is there for a reason.

Comment: @elgonzo thanks. Just edited it to have the minimal code needed.

Comment: @paboobhzx - And the word "Complete" is there for a reason too. When I copy and paste your code into my dev environment I get a boat load of compiler errors. Can you please fix?

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks. Fixed it. Thanks for the patience. Reduced it to the minimal needs.

Comment: @paboobhzx - So you are just simply adding files to the processor and processing them on a background thread? Then you just continue to loop to see if there are more files and you repeat?

Comment: @paboobhzx - But you want a way of cancelling the work, when you close the form, for example?

Comment: @Enigmativity A timer runs each X seconds. When the countdown finishes, if there are files to be processed they are processed on a background thread. After processing i want to delete those files. But i do always get IOException errors, even after manually interrupting the thread. I was using an async\await before but the problem was the same.

Comment: @paboobhzx - Can you please show the complete code that processes the files? Without that it's not possible to answer the question.

Comment: @Enigmativity this is the complete FileProcessor class. I haven't listed it here because its too much code and do so much stuff. But there it is.https://pastebin.com/2Sp8DbGK

Comment: @Enigmativity note: The eventwaithandle.Set() is called from the main thread (form thread). The background thread class doesn't know when it should process its file queue so the main thread signals it to begin working.

Comment: So the idea is you are polling a directory for new files, you process them and then when they are finished processing you want to delete the file, rinse and repeat?

Comment: @paboobhzx - You are doing some crazy things in your code. Stuff like `var IZDraw = Task.Run(() => InkZoneAreaImage(IZDataInfo.Result.IzArea_ZoneAreaWidth, IZDataInfo.Result.IzArea_ZoneAreaHeight), cancelParallelWorker.Token); Task.WaitAll(IZDraw);`.

Comment: The problem is your code and logic is a mess (term used nicely), and its hard to understand what you are actually trying to do

Comment: @Enigmativity this is a a task that sometimes takes too long to complete (it draws an white picture that sometimes its 10000x10000h. Thats why i'm waiting until its done.

Comment: @MichaelRandall critics \ comments about the logic and the code are always welcome. But basically you mentioned what i'm doing. Check the directory, if there are files to process run the background thread, delete after everything is done and repeat.

Comment: @paboobhzx - But writing `InkZoneAreaImage(IZDataInfo.Result.IzArea_ZoneAreaWidth, IZDataInfo.Result.IzArea_ZoneAreaHeight)` would be the same and a lot less messy.

Comment: @Enigmativity if i do so i can't access the Task.Result . Thats why i'm storing the result inside a variable.

Comment: @paboobhzx - Sorry, you would just do `var result = InkZoneAreaImage(IZDataInfo.Result.IzArea_ZoneAreaWidth, IZDataInfo.Result.IzArea_ZoneAreaHeight)`

Comment: @Enigmativity agreed. That's something to change and will make it better readable since its only one task (no multi tasking). I haven't paid attention to this

Comment: @paboobhzx - I've added an answer, but I suspect you'll need some help in adapting it to your specific needs. Let me know what questions you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is insanely complex for what you're trying to do and it's no wonder that somewhere you've left a handle for a file open on a different thread and that's preventing your code from being able to delete the file. Without being able to replicate the issue at this end I can even begin to figure out what you should do.

But here's the approach I'm going to suggest.

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Subject<string> _enqueue = new Subject<string>();
    private IDisposable _subscription = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string ColorSeparator = "42";
        int imageRotationNumber = 42;

        IObservable<string> query =
            from file in _enqueue
            from ImageListSorted in Observable.Start(() => ImageBuilder(file, ColorSeparator))
            from RotateCMYK in Observable.Start(() => Rotate(ImageListSorted.CMYKmages, imageRotationNumber))
            select file;

        _subscription = query.Subscribe(f => System.IO.File.Delete(f));

        _enqueue.OnNext(@"C:\test\yourtestfile1.txt");
        _enqueue.OnNext(@"C:\test\yourtestfile2.txt");
        _enqueue.OnNext(@"C:\test\yourtestfile3.txt");
    }


    private CreateCMYKAndImpositionImageList ImageBuilder(string JobImages, string colorDelimiter)
    {
        return new CreateCMYKAndImpositionImageList(JobImages, colorDelimiter);
    }

    private RotateImages Rotate(Dictionary<string, string> imageList, int RotationNumber)
    {
        return new RotateImages(imageList, RotationNumber);
    }
}
```

Now, I've only included two steps in your process, but you should be able to continue the logic through the rest of the steps.

Each step is run asynchronously and the entire thing can be cancelled anytime by calling `_subscription.Dispose();`.

The final `.Subscribe(f => System.IO.File.Delete(f))` can only be hit once all of the steps are complete.

So as long as you avoid anything relating to threading and tasks then this should run quite cleanly.

Comment: But by using this the UI will be locked until everything is done ?

Comment: @paboobhzx - No, not at all. It's all done in the background.