# Delete files after Observable() Operations

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I've got some observable operations running on a collection (Dictionary>), where the string is an job name and the List are the files related to this job name.

If i convert the List to an Observable it will run all operations by the number of the elements of the list. Therefore, after all operations i can delete the files.

In order to avoid this i converted the Dictionary keys to another observable. But when i do so i can't delete the files related to the key (the values(List)).

Is there any workaround for this ? I know that it will hit the Subscribe once all operations are completed. But since it runs over the key (so it won't repeat) i don't have a valid file to delete.

I'm posting the code detailed as possible.

Any input is appreciated.
Thanks

```
if (TIFFFiles.Count > 0 && ThreadRunning == false) //If there are files to be processed and nothing is already running
            {
                ThreadRunning = true;
                var toObservable = TIFFFiles.ToObservable(); //Converting the current file list to an observable
                cmb_ColorDelimiter.UIThread(() => cmb_tiffSelectedIndex = cmb_ColorDelimiter.SelectedIndex); //An int value
                var ColorSeparator = new ColorSeparatorDefiner(cmb_tiffSelectedIndex).Delimiter;//An string value
                var InfoFromFiles = new List<CMYKJobInformationForDictionarySorting>();//List for sorting
                Dictionary<string, List<string>> AvailableJobsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(); //The dictionary where i sort the files received on TIFFFiles                    
                for (int i = 0; i < TIFFFiles.Count; i++)
                {
                    AvailableJobsDictionary = BuildJobsDict(TIFFFiles[i], ColorSeparator, AvailableJobsDictionary,InfoFromFiles); //The method that sorts the files from TIFFFiles
                }
                var observableKeys = AvailableJobsDictionary.Keys.ToObservable(); //Converting the dictiobary keys to an observable
                foreach(var item in AvailableJobsDictionary) //Looping trough sorted jobs
                {
                    //By iterating over the keys i can iterate only one time per job. If iterate over all TIFFFiles it will run operations by the number of elements available in TIFFFiles.
                    IObservable<string> query = from file in observableKeys 
                                                from WriteDefaultXML in Observable.Start(() => new PPFConverter.writeFinalXml(item.Key, tb_TIFFtoXMLOutputFolder.Text))
                                                from ImageListSorted in Observable.Start(() => ImageBuilder(item.Value, ColorSeparator))
                                                from DPI in Observable.Start(() => new ObtainDPI(item.Value.ElementAt(0)))
                                                from IZDataInfo in Observable.Start(() => new IZAreaDataInfo(izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_numberOfZones, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_zoneWidth,
                                                izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_firstZoneWidth, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_lastZoneWidth, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_zoneAreaWidth, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_zoneAreaHeight, DPI.DPI))
                                                from RotateCMYK in Observable.Start(() => Rotate(ImageListSorted.CMYKmages, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageRotationCount))
                                                from RotateImposition in Observable.Start(() => Rotate(ImageListSorted.ImposedImages, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageRotationCount))
                                                from IZDraw in Observable.Start(() => InkZoneAreaImage(IZDataInfo.IzArea_ZoneAreaWidth, IZDataInfo.IzArea_ZoneAreaHeight))
                                                from CMYKIZCalculation in Observable.Start(() => LevelCalc(IZDataInfo.IzArea_ZoneWidth, DPI.DPI, RotateCMYK.RotatedImgs, IZDraw.ZoneImage, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageOrientationCont))
                                                from ImposedIZCalculation in Observable.Start(() => LevelCalc(IZDataInfo.IzArea_ZoneWidth, DPI.DPI, RotateImposition.RotatedImgs, IZDraw.ZoneImage, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageOrientationCont))
                                                from CMYKResize in Observable.Start(() => ResizeCollection(RotateCMYK.RotatedImgs, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imagePreviewWidth, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imagePreviewHeight))
                                                from ImpositionResize in Observable.Start(() => ResizeCollection(RotateImposition.RotatedImgs, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imagePreviewWidth, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imagePreviewHeight))
                                                from CombineTHumbnail in Observable.Start(() => CombineImages(CMYKResize.ResizedImages, (bool)Properties.Settings.Default["TIFFtoXML_NegateImage"]))
                                                from CreateComposedImage in Observable.Start(() => new SpotImageComposer(CombineTHumbnail.FinalCombinedImage, ImpositionResize.ResizedImages, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageOrientationCont, ColorSeparator, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.TIffToXml_UnknownSpotcolorHandling))
                                                from FinalXMLWrite in Observable.Start(() => new WriteXMLData(WriteDefaultXML.finalXmlName,WriteDefaultXML.OutputFolder,CMYKIZCalculation,ImposedIZCalculation,CreateComposedImage.FinalImage,WriteDefaultXML.xmlDoc,InfoFromFiles,ColorSeparator,item.Value))
                                                select file;                        
                    if((bool)Properties.Settings.Default["TIFFtoXML_DeleteInput"])
                    {
                        _subscription = query.Subscribe(f => System.IO.File.Delete(f)); //Wanted to delete the files
                    }
                    TIFFFiles.Clear();
                    ThreadRunning = false;
                }

            }
```

---

Updated code:

```
public partial class Form1
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> sortedJobs;
    Subject<List<string>> jobsToRun;
    private int cmb_tiffSelectedIndex;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        jobsToRun = new Subject<List<string>>();
        sortedJobs = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    }
    private void SecondElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter--;
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            counter = Int32.Parse(internalSettings.TIFFtoXML_MainTimer);
            cmb_ColorDelimiter.UIThread(() => cmb_tiffSelectedIndex = cmb_ColorDelimiter.SelectedIndex); //An int value      
            foreach (var item in sortedJobs.Values) //Each list string contains information about an job and its respective files
            {
                jobsToRun.OnNext(item);
                IObservable<List<string>> query = from currItem in jobsToRun
                                                  let ColorSeparator = new ColorSeparatorDefiner(cmb_tiffSelectedIndex).Delimiter
                                                  let JobInfo = new CMYKJobInformationForDictionarySorting(item.ElementAt(0), ColorSeparator)
                                                  let file = JobInfo.ConventionName
                                                  select currItem;
                _subscription = query.Subscribe(x =>
                {
                    if ((bool)Properties.Settings.Default["TIFFtoXML_DeleteInput"])
                    {
                        foreach (var currFile in x)
                            File.Delete(currFile);
                            //Wanted to delete the files
                        }
                });
                string r = string.Empty;
            }
            timer1.Start();
        }
        tb_MainTimer.Text = counter.ToString();
    }
    private void TIFFtoXMLEventHandler(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string fNameExt = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath).ToUpper();
        if (new GetAvailableFile(e.FullPath).fileReady)
        {
            if (fNameExt.Contains(".TIF"))
            {
                SortFilesOnArrival(e.FullPath, cmb_tiffSelectedIndex);
            }
            else if (fNameExt.Contains(".CIP") || fNameExt.Contains(".PPF"))
            {

            }
        }
        counter = Int32.Parse(internalSettings.TIFFtoXML_MainTimer);
        // timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Start();
    }
    private void SortFilesOnArrival(string currFile, int ColorDelimiterIndex)
    {
        var colorSeparator = new ColorSeparatorDefiner(ColorDelimiterIndex).Delimiter;
        CMYKJobInformationForDictionarySorting InfoFromFiles = new CMYKJobInformationForDictionarySorting(currFile, colorSeparator);
        if (sortedJobs.ContainsKey(InfoFromFiles.ConventionName))
        {
            sortedJobs[InfoFromFiles.ConventionName].Add(InfoFromFiles.OriginalFileName);
        }
        else
        {
            sortedJobs.Add(InfoFromFiles.ConventionName, new List<string>() { InfoFromFiles.OriginalFileName });
        }
        FilesCopiedInfo.Add(InfoFromFiles);
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE:
I've edited to include the final code for everything i did =) ! It worked in the end, now i'm just setting a few more details (more about the business logic and workflow). I know it is far away from good, but for now its what i decided to do. My next goal is to have a single Subscription to all kind of files and handles the different cases on the query itself ; it will make things easier and allows me to do the same thing with less code.
And thanks in advance for your help. This was like an introduction of Reactive Extensions for me heh, i'm starting to read and dig about it.

```
public partial class Form1 : AsyncBaseDialog
{
        private IDisposable CIP3Subscription = null;
        static System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1; //The timer is used but just for visual purposes - nothing is related to him
        IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> TIFFFilesCreated;
        IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> TIFFGroupFiles;
        IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> CIP3FilesCreated;
        IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> CIP3GroupFiles;
        bool currStatus = (bool)Properties.Settings.Default["TIFFtoXML_EnabledConversion"]; //If the enable conversion checkbox is enabled, fire the observable
            if(currStatus)
            {
                EnableTIFFtoXMLWatcher(currStatus); 
                EnableCIP3toTIFFWatcher(currStatus);
            }
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(SecondElapsed);
            timer1.Enabled = currStatus;
            counter = Convert.ToInt32(Properties.Settings.Default.TIFFtoXML_MainTimer);
}        
 #region timerStuff
        DateTime start;
        double s;
        private void CountDown()
        {
            start = DateTime.Now;
            s = (double)counter;        
            timer1.Start();
        }
        private void SecondElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double remainingSeconds = s - (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds;
            if (remainingSeconds <= 0)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                timer1.Interval = (int)counter;
                timer1.Start();
                CountDown();
            }
            var x = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(remainingSeconds);
            tb_MainTimer.Text = x.Seconds.ToString();
        }
        #endregion
        #region ObservableMethods //Methods i built in order to handle the observable behaviour
        private IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> CreateObjectForConvertAll(string inputFolder, string extension)
        {            
        //I've a checkbox where the user selects "Convert all", and it will convert everything in the folder. Since i didn't wanted to repeat
        //code by calling all methods again, this method returns me an object i can query

            List<FileSystemEventArgs> tempList = new List<FileSystemEventArgs>(Directory.GetFiles(tb_TIFFtoXMLInputFolder.Text, extension, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList()
                            .Select(x => new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.Created, "", x)));
            List<FileSystemEventArgs[]> fswArgsArrayList = new List<FileSystemEventArgs[]>();           
            fswArgsArrayList.Add(tempList.ToArray());
            var finalObservable = fswArgsArrayList.ToArray();
            var finalObservableNotArray = finalObservable.ToArray().ToObservable();
            return finalObservableNotArray;
        }
        private IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> CreateReactiveFSWInstance(string inputFolder, string fileFilter, bool checkBoxStatus)
        {
            //Creates the Reactive FSW instance
            //checkBoxStatus => Enabled or not ; if the user enables the conversion, EnableRaisingEvents will be true
            IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> filesCreated =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () =>
            {
                var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(inputFolder)
                {
                    EnableRaisingEvents = checkBoxStatus,
                    Filter = fileFilter
                };
                return fsw;
            },
            fsw => Observable.FromEventPattern
                <FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                h => fsw.Created += h,
                h => fsw.Created -= h))
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs);
            return filesCreated;
        }        
        private IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> TIFFPublish(IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> observable)
        {
            var GroupFiles =
                 observable
                     .Publish(fc =>
                         from w in fc.Window(() => fc.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)counter)))
                         from fcs in w.ToArray()
                         select fcs);
            return GroupFiles;
        }
        #endregion 
        private void StartCIP3ProcessingQuery(IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> Files)
        {
            //query goes here...
        }
         private void StartTIFFProcessingQuery(IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> Files)
        {
            //query goes here...
        }
        private void EnableTIFFtoXMLWatcher(bool status)
        {
            //Enable the reactive watcher for TIF files
            TIFFFilesCreated = CreateReactiveFSWInstance(tb_TIFFtoXMLInputFolder.Text, "*.tif", status);
            TIFFGroupFiles = TIFFPublish(TIFFFilesCreated);
            StartTIFFProcessingQuery(TIFFGroupFiles);
        }
        private void EnableCIP3toTIFFWatcher(bool status)
        {
            //Enable the reactive watcher for CIP3 files
            CIP3FilesCreated = CreateReactiveFSWInstance(tb_TIFFtoXMLInputFolder.Text, "*.*", status);
            CIP3GroupFiles = TIFFPublish(CIP3FilesCreated);
            StartCIP3ProcessingQuery(CIP3GroupFiles, false);
        }
        private void SubscriptionDisposal()
        {
            //Disposal methods
            TIFFSubscription.Dispose();
            CIP3Subscription.Dispose();
        }
        //Enable or disable the conversio, or convert all
        private void CheckboxChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox CurrChk = sender as CheckBox;
            bool status = CurrChk.Checked;
            switch (CurrChk.Name)
            {
                case "TIFFtoXML_chkConvertAll":
                    {
                        if(status)
                        {
                           cb_enableTIFFtoXML.Checked = true; //Enabling this checkbox triggers the other case and fires the FSW
                            var convertAllTIFFObj = CreateObjectForConvertAll(tb_TIFFtoXMLInputFolder.Text, "*.tif");
                            StartTIFFProcessingQuery(convertAllTIFFObj);
                            var convertAllCIP3Obj = CreateObjectForConvertAll(tb_TIFFtoXMLInputFolder.Text, "*.*");
                            StartCIP3ProcessingQuery(convertAllCIP3Obj,true);                            
                            CurrChk.Checked = false;
                        }        
                        break;
                    }
                case "cb_enableTIFFtoXML":
                    {
                        if (status)
                        {
                            EnableCIP3toTIFFWatcher(status);
                            EnableTIFFtoXMLWatcher(status);
                            CountDown();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //If the user disables the conversion, it will just dispose objects.
                            TIFFSubscription.Dispose();
                            CIP3Subscription.Dispose();
                            timer1.Stop();
                        }

                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I did say to you to avoid using any threads operations - Observables create their own threads.

Comment: You have a way of making things very complicated. An observable only runs when you subscribe so the `if ((bool)Properties.Settings.Default["TIFFtoXML_DeleteInput"])` means that the observable doesn't ruin unless you are deleting the files.

Comment: Observables create their own threads so by the time that the first `Observable.Start(() => new PPFConverter.writeFinalXml(item.Key, tb_TIFFtoXMLOutputFolder.Text))` even begins you're calling the `ThreadRunning = false;` code.

Comment: And again, a [mcve] be awesome here.

Comment: You should have used the `Subject<string>` approach that I gave you in your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55034244/cant-delete-a-file-after-thread-is-interrupted question.

Comment: Your code in `for (int i = 0; i < TIFFFiles.Count; i++)` makes no sense as it's just throwing away the value of `AvailableJobsDictionary` for each `i`.

Comment: When editing make sure you don't invalidate existing answers. Usually that means once an answer is given you should append the update at the end.

Comment: Please don't edit other people's answers (unless it is a simple or typographical error) - you can add to the end of your question or post another answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a closer version of what your code should look like:

```
IObservable<string> query =
    from item in TIFFFiles // TIFFFiles = new Subject<string>()
    let ColorSeparator = new ColorSeparatorDefiner(cmb_tiffSelectedIndex).Delimiter
    let jobInfo = new CMYKJobInformationForDictionarySorting(currFile, ColorSeparator)
    let file = jobInfo.ConventionName
    from WriteDefaultXML in Observable.Start(() => new PPFConverter.writeFinalXml(item.Key, tb_TIFFtoXMLOutputFolder.Text))
    from ImageListSorted in Observable.Start(() => ImageBuilder(item.Value, ColorSeparator))
    from DPI in Observable.Start(() => new ObtainDPI(item.Value.ElementAt(0)))
    from IZDataInfo in Observable.Start(() => new IZAreaDataInfo(izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_numberOfZones, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_zoneWidth, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_firstZoneWidth, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_lastZoneWidth, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_zoneAreaWidth, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_zoneAreaHeight, DPI.DPI))
    from RotateCMYK in Observable.Start(() => Rotate(ImageListSorted.CMYKmages, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageRotationCount))
    from RotateImposition in Observable.Start(() => Rotate(ImageListSorted.ImposedImages, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageRotationCount))
    from IZDraw in Observable.Start(() => InkZoneAreaImage(IZDataInfo.IzArea_ZoneAreaWidth, IZDataInfo.IzArea_ZoneAreaHeight))
    from CMYKIZCalculation in Observable.Start(() => LevelCalc(IZDataInfo.IzArea_ZoneWidth, DPI.DPI, RotateCMYK.RotatedImgs, IZDraw.ZoneImage, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageOrientationCont))
    from ImposedIZCalculation in Observable.Start(() => LevelCalc(IZDataInfo.IzArea_ZoneWidth, DPI.DPI, RotateImposition.RotatedImgs, IZDraw.ZoneImage, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageOrientationCont))
    from CMYKResize in Observable.Start(() => ResizeCollection(RotateCMYK.RotatedImgs, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imagePreviewWidth, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imagePreviewHeight))
    from ImpositionResize in Observable.Start(() => ResizeCollection(RotateImposition.RotatedImgs, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imagePreviewWidth, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imagePreviewHeight))
    from CombineTHumbnail in Observable.Start(() => CombineImages(CMYKResize.ResizedImages, (bool)Properties.Settings.Default["TIFFtoXML_NegateImage"]))
    from CreateComposedImage in Observable.Start(() => new SpotImageComposer(CombineTHumbnail.FinalCombinedImage, ImpositionResize.ResizedImages, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageOrientationCont, ColorSeparator, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.TIffToXml_UnknownSpotcolorHandling))
    from FinalXMLWrite in Observable.Start(() => new WriteXMLData(WriteDefaultXML.finalXmlName, WriteDefaultXML.OutputFolder, CMYKIZCalculation, ImposedIZCalculation, CreateComposedImage.FinalImage, WriteDefaultXML.xmlDoc, InfoFromFiles, ColorSeparator, item.Value))
    select file;

_subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(f =>
        {
            if ((bool)Properties.Settings.Default["TIFFtoXML_DeleteInput"])
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(f); //Wanted to delete the files
            }
        }, () =>
        {
            /* code to execute when observable finishes */
            /* You must call `TIFFFiles.OnCompleted()` */
        });
```

Please do not use any timers, threads, or tasks. If you do say why and I can help you fix it to what you need.

All of this gets triggered when you call: `TIFFFiles.OnNext(filename);`.

---

Here's the code that observes the file system and then groups changes together based on there being `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0)` of no further files being added:

```
IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> filesCreated =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () =>
            {
                var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\james\Temporary\Testing");
                fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                return fsw;
            },
            fsw => Observable.FromEventPattern
                <FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                h => fsw.Created += h,
                h => fsw.Created -= h))
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> batchesOfFilesCreated =
    filesCreated
        .Publish(fc =>
            from w in fc.Window(() => fc.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0)))
            from fcs in w.ToArray()
            select fcs);
```

Now your query looks like this:

```
var ColorSeparator = new ColorSeparatorDefiner(cmb_tiffSelectedIndex).Delimiter;

var query =
    from gfcs in batchesOfFilesCreated.GroupBy(x => new CMYKJobInformationForDictionarySorting(currFile, ColorSeparator).ConventionName)
    let file = gfcs.Key
    from gfc in gfcs
    from WriteDefaultXML in Observable.Start(() => new PPFConverter.writeFinalXml(item.Key, tb_TIFFtoXMLOutputFolder.Text))
    from ImageListSorted in Observable.Start(() => ImageBuilder(item.Value, ColorSeparator))
    from DPI in Observable.Start(() => new ObtainDPI(item.Value.ElementAt(0)))
    from IZDataInfo in Observable.Start(() => new IZAreaDataInfo(izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_numberOfZones, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_zoneWidth, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_firstZoneWidth, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_lastZoneWidth, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_zoneAreaWidth, izAreaSettings.FrmIZArea_zoneAreaHeight, DPI.DPI))
    from RotateCMYK in Observable.Start(() => Rotate(ImageListSorted.CMYKmages, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageRotationCount))
    from RotateImposition in Observable.Start(() => Rotate(ImageListSorted.ImposedImages, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageRotationCount))
    from IZDraw in Observable.Start(() => InkZoneAreaImage(IZDataInfo.IzArea_ZoneAreaWidth, IZDataInfo.IzArea_ZoneAreaHeight))
    from CMYKIZCalculation in Observable.Start(() => LevelCalc(IZDataInfo.IzArea_ZoneWidth, DPI.DPI, RotateCMYK.RotatedImgs, IZDraw.ZoneImage, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageOrientationCont))
    from ImposedIZCalculation in Observable.Start(() => LevelCalc(IZDataInfo.IzArea_ZoneWidth, DPI.DPI, RotateImposition.RotatedImgs, IZDraw.ZoneImage, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageOrientationCont))
    from CMYKResize in Observable.Start(() => ResizeCollection(RotateCMYK.RotatedImgs, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imagePreviewWidth, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imagePreviewHeight))
    from ImpositionResize in Observable.Start(() => ResizeCollection(RotateImposition.RotatedImgs, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imagePreviewWidth, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imagePreviewHeight))
    from CombineTHumbnail in Observable.Start(() => CombineImages(CMYKResize.ResizedImages, (bool)Properties.Settings.Default["TIFFtoXML_NegateImage"]))
    from CreateComposedImage in Observable.Start(() => new SpotImageComposer(CombineTHumbnail.FinalCombinedImage, ImpositionResize.ResizedImages, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.FrmTiffPng_imageOrientationCont, ColorSeparator, tiffToXmlpngPreviewSettings.TIffToXml_UnknownSpotcolorHandling))
    from FinalXMLWrite in Observable.Start(() => new WriteXMLData(WriteDefaultXML.finalXmlName, WriteDefaultXML.OutputFolder, CMYKIZCalculation, ImposedIZCalculation, CreateComposedImage.FinalImage, WriteDefaultXML.xmlDoc, InfoFromFiles, ColorSeparator, item.Value))
    select file;

_subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(f =>
        {
            if ((bool)Properties.Settings.Default["TIFFtoXML_DeleteInput"])
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(f); //Wanted to delete the files
        }
        }, () =>
        {
        /* code to execute when observable finishes */
        /* You must call `TIFFFiles.OnCompleted()` */
        });
```

NB: This eliminates the timer and the use of threads in your code. You should be able to set this up once and leave it running. Just remember to call `_subscription.Dispose()` when you want it to stop running.

Comment: thanks. The program polls for file every x seconds (user defined). Files are added using a FileSystemWatcher.OnCreated() . After the timer runs out, i sort all those files into a dictionary and only then i'm ready to work with it. I will try to adapt your solution to mine. But i already have an idea, i need to add this dictionary to the observable threads collection so everything will run sequentially.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use your example. I can't add items to the Subject < string>, so i still need an List<string> and later convert it to an Observable(). However if i have 6 elements in the Observable collection all operations will run six times ; and thats the wrong behaviour. You see, a job can have multiple files attached to it ; all those multiple files will be processed as a single job, not one processing for each file. And this is where my logic is failing. I understood the conceptsyou showed (also read MSDN docs )  but i can't seem to adapt it.

Comment: @paboobhzx - The observable should be something that is subscribed to once at the start of your program - it then never needs to be run again. I've suggested using a `Subject<string>()` as that seemed the closest analogy to `TIFFtoXMLProcessor.EnqueueFileName(@"C:\test\yourtestfile1.txt");`, but you're now telling me that you use `FileSystemWatcher.OnCreated`. Observables can be triggered by events so you can make an observable that automatically runs when files are created.

Comment: @paboobhzx - This all goes back to create a good [mcve] of what you're trying to do. Are you only running multiple files in a job because you are collecting newly created files between each timer run?

Comment: it’s exactly that. A checkbox defines if the FSW is enabled or not. If it’s enabled a timer runs and the FSW gets all files created on the folder. When the timer runs out if there are files added to this list it will process them. I defined jobs to be key/pair where key is a short file name and the value are the file names related to this key.  I’ll create a complete example and post and edit here.

Comment: @paboobhzx - Is there a reason that they are batch in groups and not just processed as soon as the file is created?

Comment: yes there is. A job is composed by one or more files, i do not know how many files it will have. Thats why i wait until the timer runs out and then sort them accordingly.

Comment: i've edited the post. There it is my current approach to the issue. I'm sorting the files as soon they arrive. Then i run a loop on the dictionary values (List<string>) and trigger each one to be processed.

Comment: @paboobhzx - Oh, so you're waiting until all of the files have been added to the folder?

Comment: exactly. I do wait until no more files are added to the folder. Everytime a file is added the timer restarts. When no more files have been copied i start to do stuff.

Comment: @paboobhzx - So how long after the the last file is added do you wait to start?

Comment: the user set this timer. But it’s usually 30-60 seconds. The minimal value is 10 seconds. It’s the approach I’m using

Comment: Your solutions works, really fine. I also started to read about the Reactive Framework. I've got two more questions: 1) If i have more than one result from the batchesofFileCreates.GroupBy (suppose, two dictionaries) how to iterate over them ? And you know where i could get an example of attaching a progress bar to watch the progress the the query ? Thanks !

Comment: @paboobhzx - you can have more than one group in the `GroupBy`, but the code already handles it. You can use the `.Do` operator to intercept the observable pipeline to send values to a progress bar.

Comment: sorry - edited yout answer by mistake. Posted it here as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I've edited to include the final code for everything i did =) ! It worked in the end, now i'm just setting a few more details (more about the business logic and workflow). I know it is far away from good, but for now its what i decided to do.

My next goal is to have a single Subscription to all kind of files and handles the different cases on the query itself ; it will make things easier and allows me to do the same thing with less code. And thanks in advance for your help. This was like an introduction of Reactive Extensions for me heh, i'm starting to read and dig about it.

```
public partial class Form1 : AsyncBaseDialog
{
        private IDisposable CIP3Subscription = null;
        static System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1; //The timer is used but just for visual purposes - nothing is related to him
        IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> TIFFFilesCreated;
        IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> TIFFGroupFiles;
        IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> CIP3FilesCreated;
        IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> CIP3GroupFiles;
        bool currStatus = (bool)Properties.Settings.Default["TIFFtoXML_EnabledConversion"]; //If the enable conversion checkbox is enabled, fire the observable
            if(currStatus)
            {
                EnableTIFFtoXMLWatcher(currStatus); 
                EnableCIP3toTIFFWatcher(currStatus);
            }
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(SecondElapsed);
            timer1.Enabled = currStatus;
            counter = Convert.ToInt32(Properties.Settings.Default.TIFFtoXML_MainTimer);
}        
 #region timerStuff
        DateTime start;
        double s;
        private void CountDown()
        {
            start = DateTime.Now;
            s = (double)counter;        
            timer1.Start();
        }
        private void SecondElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double remainingSeconds = s - (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds;
            if (remainingSeconds <= 0)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                timer1.Interval = (int)counter;
                timer1.Start();
                CountDown();
            }
            var x = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(remainingSeconds);
            tb_MainTimer.Text = x.Seconds.ToString();
        }
        #endregion
        #region ObservableMethods //Methods i built in order to handle the observable behaviour
        private IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> CreateObjectForConvertAll(string inputFolder, string extension)
        {            
        //I've a checkbox where the user selects "Convert all", and it will convert everything in the folder. Since i didn't wanted to repeat
        //code by calling all methods again, this method returns me an object i can query

            List<FileSystemEventArgs> tempList = new List<FileSystemEventArgs>(Directory.GetFiles(tb_TIFFtoXMLInputFolder.Text, extension, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList()
                            .Select(x => new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.Created, "", x)));
            List<FileSystemEventArgs[]> fswArgsArrayList = new List<FileSystemEventArgs[]>();           
            fswArgsArrayList.Add(tempList.ToArray());
            var finalObservable = fswArgsArrayList.ToArray();
            var finalObservableNotArray = finalObservable.ToArray().ToObservable();
            return finalObservableNotArray;
        }
        private IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> CreateReactiveFSWInstance(string inputFolder, string fileFilter, bool checkBoxStatus)
        {
            //Creates the Reactive FSW instance
            //checkBoxStatus => Enabled or not ; if the user enables the conversion, EnableRaisingEvents will be true
            IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> filesCreated =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () =>
            {
                var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(inputFolder)
                {
                    EnableRaisingEvents = checkBoxStatus,
                    Filter = fileFilter
                };
                return fsw;
            },
            fsw => Observable.FromEventPattern
                <FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                h => fsw.Created += h,
                h => fsw.Created -= h))
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs);
            return filesCreated;
        }        
        private IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> TIFFPublish(IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> observable)
        {
            var GroupFiles =
                 observable
                     .Publish(fc =>
                         from w in fc.Window(() => fc.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)counter)))
                         from fcs in w.ToArray()
                         select fcs);
            return GroupFiles;
        }
        #endregion 
        private void StartCIP3ProcessingQuery(IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> Files)
        {
            //query goes here...
        }
         private void StartTIFFProcessingQuery(IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs[]> Files)
        {
            //query goes here...
        }
        private void EnableTIFFtoXMLWatcher(bool status)
        {
            //Enable the reactive watcher for TIF files
            TIFFFilesCreated = CreateReactiveFSWInstance(tb_TIFFtoXMLInputFolder.Text, "*.tif", status);
            TIFFGroupFiles = TIFFPublish(TIFFFilesCreated);
            StartTIFFProcessingQuery(TIFFGroupFiles);
        }
        private void EnableCIP3toTIFFWatcher(bool status)
        {
            //Enable the reactive watcher for CIP3 files
            CIP3FilesCreated = CreateReactiveFSWInstance(tb_TIFFtoXMLInputFolder.Text, "*.*", status);
            CIP3GroupFiles = TIFFPublish(CIP3FilesCreated);
            StartCIP3ProcessingQuery(CIP3GroupFiles, false);
        }
        private void SubscriptionDisposal()
        {
            //Disposal methods
            TIFFSubscription.Dispose();
            CIP3Subscription.Dispose();
        }
        //Enable or disable the conversio, or convert all
        private void CheckboxChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox CurrChk = sender as CheckBox;
            bool status = CurrChk.Checked;
            switch (CurrChk.Name)
            {
                case "TIFFtoXML_chkConvertAll":
                    {
                        if(status)
                        {
                           cb_enableTIFFtoXML.Checked = true; //Enabling this checkbox triggers the other case and fires the FSW
                            var convertAllTIFFObj = CreateObjectForConvertAll(tb_TIFFtoXMLInputFolder.Text, "*.tif");
                            StartTIFFProcessingQuery(convertAllTIFFObj);
                            var convertAllCIP3Obj = CreateObjectForConvertAll(tb_TIFFtoXMLInputFolder.Text, "*.*");
                            StartCIP3ProcessingQuery(convertAllCIP3Obj,true);                            
                            CurrChk.Checked = false;
                        }        
                        break;
                    }
                case "cb_enableTIFFtoXML":
                    {
                        if (status)
                        {
                            EnableCIP3toTIFFWatcher(status);
                            EnableTIFFtoXMLWatcher(status);
                            CountDown();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //If the user disables the conversion, it will just dispose objects.
                            TIFFSubscription.Dispose();
                            CIP3Subscription.Dispose();
                            timer1.Stop();
                        }

                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
```